# How to get the content of ckeditor4 with images in the node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs, ckeditor4.x

I have blog application created in nodejs. I use ckeditor4 to add and edit posts. The content in the textarea together with the image is saved in the database and displayed in edit form for editing content. However, it doesn't show an image on post detail page (text is showed).

I see in the database the image stored as blob. The record in column 'content' in the table 'posts' is bellow:

```
<p>Web application in node</p>
<figure class="easyimage easyimage-full"><img alt="" src="blob:http://localhost:3000/67c0a58-203-69a-84a5-c61acab81" width="1280" />
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
<p>This is example</p>
```

In the my detail page 'detail.ejs' is typed <%- post.content %> and showed only text and image not showed. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve this situation?